# es6 modules export/import: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

### Description of the problem:

I'm creating a new instance of a Hero in my GameService class constructor like so:

```
let image = Util.createImage('assets/images/head_blue.jpg');
this.hero = new Hero({
  id: 1,
  name: 'test',
  x: 0,
  y: 0,
  width: 100,
  height: 100,
  bitmap: new createjs.Bitmap(image)
});
```

I've added the `import Hero from '../entities/hero';` in my GameService. linter-jshint is not indicating any problems, and when I build the js files via gulp no errors are shown. If I put some random module name, then gulp will throw an error.

It would seem everything is fine, but I am getting this error in my browser:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'default' of undefined

This error seems to be coming directly from my Object class. If I comment `Object` out completely from the `Hero` class, the error goes away.

### Question

why would `export default Object;` be causing this problem?

### Code

---

**Class**: Hero extends Object,
**Located**: `/entities/hero.js`

```
import Object from "./object";

class Hero extends Object{
  constructor(options){
    if(options === undefined){
      throw new TypeError("Options not defined in Hero.");
    }
    super(options.x, options.y, options.width, options.height, options.bitmap);
    this._id = options.id;
    this._name = options.name;
  }
  set id(id){
    this._id = id;
  }
  get id(){
    return this._id;
  }
  set name(name){
    this._name = name;
  }
  get name(){
    return this._name;
  }
}

export default Hero;
```

---

**Class**: Object,
**Located** `/entities/object.js`

```
class Object{
  constructor(x, y, width, height, bitmap){
    this._x = x;
    this._y = y;
    this._width = width;
    this._height = height;
    this._bitmap = bitmap;
  }
  set x(x){
    this._x = this._bitmap.x = x;
  }
  get x(){
    return this._x;
  }
  set y(y){
    this._y = this._bitmap.y = y;
  }
  get y(){
    return this._y;
  }
  set width(width){
    this._width = width;
  }
  get width(){
    return this._width;
  }
  set height(height){
    this._height = height;
  }
  get height(){
    return this._height;
  }
  set bitmap(bitmap){
    this._bitmap = bitmap;
  }
  get bitmap(){
    return this._bitmap;
  }
}

export default Object;
```

---

**Folder Structure:**

When I do `this.hero = new Hero({ /* stuff here */ });` I am in the game.service.js file (aka: GameService class).

[image]

Comment: I dunno, but `Object` is a horrible name for your base class - [`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) already is *the* base class.

Comment: @Bergi, that was the problem. I renamed it to BaseObject, and it works. Thanks.

Comment: Good to have it working. Still I think you should report it as a bug with your transpiler, afaics it *should* have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) already is the base class - [Bergi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi)

He mentioned that it's possibly a bug in my transpiler and it should have worked. For now, I have just renamed `Object` to `BaseObject`.